# Unable to mount mobile wifi

Tags: wireless, 16.04, huawei, usb-modeswitch

I have a wireless USB dongle from Huawei.

On Windows, it open a storage drive when connected, just like a normal USB drive. From there I would install the drivers and then use the internet.

On Ubuntu 14.04 it was simple: I would just plug it in and it would work. But ever since I upgraded to 16.04, it doesn't work that way. Sometimes it would open the USB storage and would not connect to the internet, other times it would connect to the internet. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1532:000e Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1b1c:0c04 Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 413c:2110 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:1010 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

[image: this is the error that i get]

Comment: You are not supposed to mount it. Do add the output of `lspci -nnk` to the question.

Comment: @mikewhatever, "Unable to mount mobile wifi" is the error message that i get sometimes, currently im on a laptop and its working fine here, i'll add the ouput of the laptop here and i'll put the output of my other system later.

Comment: @mikewhatever here you go 
http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/2SM8

Comment: You probably need to install the `usb-modeswitch` package. There's a good chance the device will be switched from storage to wireless the next time you connect it after the installation. Otherwise you may need to try manual mode switching with `sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 1506` and see if that helps. Please report back with the result so I can write an answer.

Comment: @DavidFoerster aah sorry for late response, been busy, i'll give it a go and let you know.